# iOS10,use ChineseKeyboard,The InputTextField's Correction Not show correcly

Tags: keyboard, textfield, ios10

In my iOS Simulator,I have set the language and keyboardtype to Chinese.

And in my project1,when I input some words such as 'xiangrik',the keyboard's correction words dosen't show correctly, the correction words in keyboard don't show fully,

**It looks wrong like '...葵'**

[image]
 hi

And this will happen all the place where I use UITextfield or UITextView.

.

But in my another project2, it seems all right

**It looks right show fully like '向日葵'**

[image]

Is there anything wrong in my project1?

Answer (score 0):

We have found the reason.
It was that **The Text Font We Used** is not **SystemFont**;

We have overridden the system method 
`- (UIFont* )systemFontOfSize:(CGFloat)`
to return another font (HelveticaNeue),maybe the customFont we used is not support on iOS10.